# Determining closest neighbor in 3 dimensional space

Tags: math

I'm trying to find out the closest neighbor of a point A in a 3 dimensional space.
There are several points present in point A's neighborhood.

I would now like to know which point is closest to point A.

I can calculate the distance of X, Y and Z for point A to each other point, but I don't know how to put this into a formula.

Let's say point A's X coordinate is 0 units different to point B's X coordinate, and point A's Y coordinate is 1 unit different to point B's Y coordinate, and point A's Z coordinate is 1 unit different to point B's Z coordinate.

At first I thought I could simply add these 3 difference to sum a single distance variable, but in the case of point C's X difference being 0, C's Y difference being 0 and C's Z difference being 2, I don't see if point B or point C would be closer to point A.

Could anybody share his ideas about this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math and not programming. There is http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance from point A to B in 3 dimensional space is calculated as follows:

```
distance = sqrt((b.x-A.x)^2+(B.y-A.y)^2+(B.z-A.z)^2)
```

To find the minimum you have to iterate your points. Lets say `candidates` is the set of Points you want to find the closest neighbor. And the Point neighbor will be the closest point to four point a.

```
Point a = new Point(0,0,0);
Point neighbor = null;
int min = INTEGER.MAX_VALUE;
for(Point p : candidates){
     distance = sqrt((b.x-A.x)^2+(B.y-A.y)^2+(B.z-A.z)^2)
     if( distance < min){
         distance : min
         neighbor = p
     }
}
```

If you don't want to return the distance-value you can do it without the sqrt and save this expensive operation.

Comment: Would it matter if some coordinates are negative? Do I have to threat them in a special way?

Comment: No you dont have to. This solution is working on  all coordinates. (+/-)

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in math.stackexchange already:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/calculate-distance-in-3d-space

Summary: The distance formula is `Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz)` where dx, dy, dz are the component coordinate differences.

To find the minimum, you don't need to calculate the root, but you still need to square the components of the sum (because for a,b > 0: sqrt(a) > sqrt(b) if a > b)

Comment: Your formula is only correct if the Point A is ``0/0/0``. Otherwise you have to calc ``sqrt((b.x-A.x)^2+(B.y-A.y)^2+(B.z-A.z)^2)``

Comment: Added an explanation

Comment: okay now i understand.. +1

Comment: Thanks. Note that you can omit sqrt() in your solution if you just need to find the minimum. I usually call the variable distanceSqared to avoid surprises later.

Comment: Sure, I mentioned it in the last sentence ;)